# Permitir valor null em campo de relacionamento

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Eu tenho um banco de dados `MySQL` com tabelas `t1` e `t2`. Uma das colunas na tabela `t1` tem uma chave estrangeira para `t2`.

Precisa permitir que a coluna de chave estrangeira aceite valores `null`. Já existem dados importantes nelas, a recriação da tabela não é uma opção.

Estou usando o `phpMyAdmin` para manipulação do banco de dados

Tentei o seguinte comando:

```
ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY fk_t2 INT NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aparenta funcionar, mas quando abro a tabela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**Entenda-se o seguinte, a tabela t1 seria uma ordem de venda, e a tabela t2 cupons, uma ordem de venda pode ter null ou 1 cupom, e um cupom pode estar referenciando null ou N ordens de venda**

A estrutura da tabela ordem de venda:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sales_order` (
  `id_sales_order` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `fk_coupons` INT NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `total_price` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ''
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_sales_order`, `fk_customer`, `fk_coupons`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `fk_sales_order_coupons1_idx` (`fk_coupons` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sales_order_coupons1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`fk_coupons`)
    REFERENCES `coupons` (`id_coupons`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
PACK_KEYS = 1
```

A estrutura da tabela cupom:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coupons` (
  `id_coupons` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `coupon_name` VARCHAR(40) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `discount` DECIMAL(9,4) NULL DEFAULT NULL COMMENT ''
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_coupons`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: O problema que vc tem agora é sempre deve existir um cupom válido (ou seja ele existe na tabela de cumpons) para um compra? A sugestão que tenho é cadastrar um cupom com o id zero por exemplo e dar a descrição de 'sem cumpom' ou 'venda sem desconto' e sempre associar esse id as compras sem desconto/cupom. Claro avalie se isso é adequado para o seu caso.

Comment: O problema é que gostaria de permitir valor null nesse cupom rs, existe um modo?

Comment: Essa é uma das possibilidades que eu pensei inicialmente @rray, mas se possível queria optar pelo valor null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pela estrutura da sua tabela `sales_order`, a coluna `fk_coupons` faz parte da chave primária.

Você não pode ter chave primária sem valor (null).

Se você realmente precisa disso e você puder tirar `fk_coupons` da PK, você pode:

```
ALTER TABLE SALES_ORDER DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

E depois:

```
ALTER TABLE SALES_ORDER ADD PRIMARY KEY (id_sales_order, fk_customer)
```

Comment: Sua resposta não foi a solução do problema, mas me fez ver qual era o problema rs

Comment: Boa! O importante é ajudar.  :)